# Is Data validation possible for username and password fields through automation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we validate username text-box with input data as "12345" or alpha-numeric or special characters.

Can we validate password text-box with input data as "12345" or alpha-numeric or special characters.

**Note:** As password field validation comes under security test cases which I think is not possible in automation..

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to validate input data for username and password fields. here is an example

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("12345");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("12345");
```

if you want to validate multipe sets of data for username and password, you can do that by removing the hardcoded values and use a variable, then pass multiple sets of data using the variables.

if you are familiar with testNG you can use @DataProvider to pass multiple sets of data to the test with variables and then validate username and password.

Answer (score -1):

It is though.

You need pattern.

I'm not exactly sure how it works, but i'd suggest you try http://w3schools.com/